# SQL Server agent backup SSAS database

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-agent

I want to use the SQl Server agent to backup one of my Analysis servers databases.

However, when I connect to my Analysis Services I have to access to the SQL server agent.

It only shows up when I connect to my Database Engine. So now when I try to schedule a backup it says it cannot find the Database. How am I supposed to do this?

Is the SQL server agent supposed to show up when connecting to my Analysis Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Agent needs access to the relational database engine, as it saves its configuration and the job execution details which you can see as the job history in tables of a relational database. Actually, it uses the `msdb` database which is part of every SQL Server relational database instance. Thus, you need to access the relational database engine in order to access SQL Server Agent. But there is no requirement that the machine running SQL Server Agent is the same as the one running Analysis Services. Both can run on different machines, and even have different versions of SQL Server.